# Why do I get the SQL error 110 although the Column number is correct?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I'm trying to insert an object into a local SQL Server database. The problem I'm facing at the moment is this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "There are fewer columns in the INSERT statement than values specified in the VALUES clause. The number of values in the VALUES clause must match the number of columns specified in the INSERT statement."

The error itself looks obvious but on the following code I don't understand it anymore.

It might be helpful to know that `Kategorie` is a foreign key from the table `Kategorien`.

The method I'm calling:

```
public static void Add(Artikel artikel)
{
    ExecuteSQL($"INSERT INTO [dbo].[Artikel] ([Id], [Name], [Preis], [Kategorie]) VALUES ('{artikel.ID}', '{artikel.Name}',{artikel.Preis}, (SELECT TOP 1 Id FROM Kategorien WHERE Id = '{artikel.Kategorie.ID}'))");
}
```

`ExecuteSQL` method:

```
private static void ExecuteSQL(string sqlText)
{
    SqlConnection connection = Init();
    SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlText, connection);
    sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

The `Artikel` table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtYrl.png)

Hopefully anyone can help me with it.

Comment: Not sure what the data types are but, if Preis is non-integer and you are using , for the decimal place then your SQL would wind up looking something like, "...VALUES (1, ArtikelNaam, 12,00, (SELECT...)" which, from SQL's perspective, looks like an additional entry rather than a float.

Comment: If you already know the Id from the category why do you insert a query in that point to retrieve the Id value?. However, you really should stop writing SQL in this way. Use parameters. What if Name contains a single quote?

Comment: If you output the 'string sqlText' that gets input to the ExecuteSQL method it might make it clearer whats gone wrong.

Comment: As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: I hope you got the point that you should be using parameters rather than string concatenation!

Answer (score 0):

First, a big thanks to @bschellekens and @Steve.
The solution was a mixture of your both comments.
The SQL Command I'm now using is:

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Artikel] ( [Id], [Name], [Preis], [Kategorie] ) VALUES ('{artikel.ID}','{artikel.Name}','{artikel.Preis}', '{artikel.Kategorie.ID}')
```

The problem was actually that the decimal amount get separated by a comma, which have confused the SQL database.

Comment: Now let's try this code with a name that contains a single quote or worse, let's set the artikel.Name property to _abc,0,0); DROP TABLE Artikel) --_ (Well It is better if you don't do that and try to understand what will happen)